# lxml XPath- filter all text including tails

Tags: python, xpath, lxml

I'm trying to filter out text from a website using lxml and Python, however, the formatting can be very irregular. (It's a forum.)

So for example, I might have:

```
<a>
   <c>
      <d>
         MARKER some text
      </d>
   </c>
   MARKER other text 1
   <b>MARKER other text 2</b>
   M<b>ARKE</b>R <e>other</e> text 3
</a>
```

I would like my xpath to return me:

```
MARKER other text 1
<b>MARKER other text 2</b>
M<b>ARKE</b>R <e>other</e> text 3
```

So in other words, I want to be able to parse nested text, but also return the text with markup.

What I currently have is:

```
filter = "//text()[not(parent::d[parent::c]) and contains(., 'MARKER')]"
filtered = root.xpath(self.vote_xpath)
for i in filtered:
    print(i)
```

where `root` is an elementtree parsed from a string, which returns me:

```
MARKER other text 1
MARKER other text 2
```

This fails in returning me the last text with the MARKER, and fails in keeping the formatting that I want.

How should I proceed from here?

EDIT:
OK, I've been fiddling a bit with the xpath.

```
//node()[not(parent::d[parent::c]) and contains(., 'MARKER')]
```

run on:

```
<a>
   <c>
      <d>
         some text
      </d>
   </c>
   other text 1
   <b>other text 2</b>
   M<b>ARKE</b>R <e>other</e> text 3
</a>
```

successfully registers the `MARKER` broken up by the `<b>` tags, since the `node()` passes the node entire to the `contains` filter. However, it returns as a match the parent node entire, in this case it simply returns the entire `<a>` node with all its contents.

How should I proceed so that the xpath returns only the matched portion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may help to look at it from a different perspective. Your semi-complete solution is focusing on parents elements of your desired data, but you could also use the child or relative path identifiers.

I got this XPATH:

```
a/c/following-sibling::node()
```

To return:

```
   MARKER other text 1

<b>MARKER other text 2</b>


   M
<b>ARKE</b>

R 
<e>other</e>

 text 3
```

And while that isn't in exactly the format you're looking for, it's the correct data, XPATH wasn't really made for formatting your results so there's not much to work with there.

Comment: Huh, that's an interesting way to look at it. This looks quite usable, thanks!